# how can i used PRINTFORM control to print a windows form in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

i used v s 2010

can any one tell me .

how can i used PRINTFORM to print my Windows form .....
can any one tell me a steps in brief....
i can not do this i am read lots of but i can not do so... and also try any alternative but i am fail...

can any one give me a source code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread from MSDN forum -

**How do I print a form in VB.NET?**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/Vsexpressvb/thread/72b5a038-912d-4455-929d-89eeb9984d7c